# Connecting to Sails.js in windows xp

Tags: sockets, sails.js

i have a simple sails chat project, when im trying to fire a message nothing is happening and in the console its just write "Connecting to Sails.js"
im using windows xp, can that be the problem ? and if so, how can i fix it? 
when im trying to run the exact code in other computer with windows 7 it works like a charm
appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an issue with Windows XP.  Check this Github issue and see if you have the same symptoms.  Then try switching browsers and see if the problem persists.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1622